# Simultaneously constrain object to point in tracked footage and distance to another tracked point

Tags: constraints, tracking

I have a movie clip which I have set up a camera track for, as I would like to capture the camera's movement in my 3D scene. I also added three additional trackers. In the tracked video, these tracked points are all collinear along an object and should form a line. After selecting the trackers and clicking "Link Empty to Track," I have three empties that, when viewed through the camera, track the three points in the video perfectly. However their depth from the camera is not known and Blender appears to have set it to some constant.

I would like to reconstruct the position of the object (shown as the red line below) in 3D space given knowledge of the distance between the three tracked points in real life. I believe this should be possible and that there wouldn't be any unconstrained degrees of freedom.

[image: viewport diagram]

I have tried adding a "Limit Distance" constraint between two of the empties, hoping to be able to get closer to a solution, but just this causes it to violate the "Follow Track" constraint they were created with. The empty I apply the limit distance constraint to moves towards the other empty, and is no longer correctly aligned with the point in the video when viewed through the camera. I was hoping both empties would have moved up directly towards the camera to settle at the set distance from one another.

[image: settings panel]

If the limit distance constraint is not the correct way to approach this problem, what other ways could I find the line that intersects the shown blue rays (as closely as possible, since they may not be coplanar) while maintaining a specified distance between the (closest) intersections?

Comment: Did you do a proper 3D Track in the Motion tracking Tab of blender and added these three empties afterwards with constraints? What is your end goal with this scene? do you want to composit 3D Elements into real footage?

Comment: @Marius I did a proper 3D camera track, as in the camera does move in 3D space and can produce similar framing as the original footage using a 3D scan of the environment I took. I'm not sure how to properly 3D track an object in the way I intend (I know planes are supported), so these empties are driven by point tracks. I do eventually intend to composite onto the original footage.

Comment: Have a look at this Video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLj7Ef8VtuA. This will give you an accurate 3D Track of your Camera. Then you place your objects in your scene. This should work for your process. I would recommend opening a new Project and doing it in there. Should you have already created Objects, you can import them into this new file via File -> Append -> (Your Blender File) -> (What you want to import (i always import collections)). Let me know if this helped :)

Comment: I actually would recommend this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vB07Bws8bmY for your specific need. The other one i mentioned above is great for understanding the motion tracking Tab but not so great for the actual tracking part. You can add your own tracking points with the add button above the detect feature button. When you want to place the objects in the viewport, open the overlay menu (Top Right, two overlapping circles) and check the Motion Tracking Checkbox. When you select your camera you will be able to see all the tracking points in 3d Space

Comment: @Marius I did follow a tutorial like that originally and my 3D camera track is working fine. The problem is that my object is moving relative to the camera and the background. I did just try adding an object track like suggested in one of those videos, but it requires 8 points to solve, and I only really have 3 to work with. I suppose I could re-shoot the video and add some giant plane with tracking points attached to the moving object, but that would be quite obtrusive and it still seems like it should be possible with the information I already have.